# How to plot a linear and quadratic model on the same graph?

Tags: r, statistics

So I have 2 models for the data set that I am using:

```
> Bears1Fit1 <- lm(Weight ~ Neck.G)
> 
> Bears2Fit2 <- lm(Weight ~ Neck.G + I(Neck.G)^2)
```

I want to plot these two models on the same scatterplot. I have this so far:

```
> plot(Neck.G, Weight, pch = c(1), main = "Black Bears Data: Weight Vs Neck Girth", xlab = "Neck Girth (inches) ", ylab = "Weight (pounds)")
> abline(Bears1Fit1)
```

However, I am unsure of how I should put the quadratic model on the same graph as well. I want to be able to have both lines on the same graph.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with cars data set:

```
data(cars)
```

make models:

```
model_lm <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
model_lm2 <- lm(speed ~ dist + I(dist^2), data = cars)
```

make new data:

```
new.data <- data.frame(dist = seq(from = min(cars$dist),
                                 to = max(cars$dist), length.out = 200))
```

predict:

```
pred_lm <- predict(model_lm, newdata = new.data)
pred_lm2 <- predict(model_lm2, newdata = new.data)
```

plot:

```
plot(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
lines(pred_lm ~ new.data$dist, col = "red")
lines(pred_lm2 ~ new.data$dist, col = "blue")
legend("topleft", c("linear", "quadratic"), col = c("red", "blue"), lty = 1)
```

[image]

with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
```

put all data in one data frame and convert to long format using `melt` from `reshape2`

```
preds <- data.frame(new.data,
                    linear = pred_lm,
                    quadratic =  pred_lm2)

preds <- reshape2::melt(preds,
                        id.vars = 1)
```

plot

```
ggplot(data = preds)+
  geom_line(aes(x = dist, y = value, color = variable ))+
  geom_point(data = cars, aes(x = dist, y = speed))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

EDIT: another way using just ggplot2 using two `geom_smooth` layers, one with the default formula `y ~ x` (so it need not be specified) and one with a quadratic model `formula = y ~ x + I(x^2)`. In order to get a legend we can specify `color` within the `aes` call naming the desired entry as we want it to show in the legend.

```
ggplot(cars,
       aes(x = dist, y = speed)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              aes(color = "linear"),
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x + I(x^2),
              aes(color = "quadratic"),
              se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]